# find line number of a word in a file

Tags: awk, grep, find, line, cpu-word

I have a file: file.txt, which contains the following data in it. GNU grep version: 2.5.1, System admin says NO to upgrading it to later version as it might impact production

```
This is a file, my name is Karl, what is this process, karl is karl junior, file is a test file, file's name is file.txt
My name is not Karl, my name is Karl Joey
What is your name?
Do you know your name and what it is?
```

When I'm running the following command to get line# of a word "is" in this file using the following command, it's giving me the output like:

**$ grep -now "is" file.txt**

```
1:is
is
is
is
is
is
2:is
is
3:is
4:is
```

**What command can I run to get the following output:**

```
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
2:is
2:is
3:is
4:is
```

**OR**

```
is:1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

If I'm trying the following command, I'm getting close but I want to replace 1 with is and is with 1 (comma separated)
**grep -now "is"  file.txt | tr '\012' ' '| sed "s/([0-9]:)/\n\1/g" | grep "."**

```
1:is is is is is is
2:is is
3:is
4:is
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `perl` then here is using their [last match start (@-)](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#pod13) and [last match end (@+)](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#pod11):

```
perl -lne '
while ($_ =~ /\bis\b/g) {
    print "$.:", substr($_, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]);
}' file
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
2:is
2:is
3:is
4:is
```

New format based on OP's request:

```
perl -lne '
    $found =()= /\bis\b/g;
    print substr($_, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]), ":", join (",", ($.) x $found);
' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

Using GNU `awk` for word boundaries:

```
gawk '{
    n = gsub(/\<is\>/,"");
    printf "%s:", "is"; 
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", NR, (i==n?RS:",")
}' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

Using vanilla `awk` (Courtesy [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336239/find-line-number-of-a-word-in-a-file/25336554?noredirect=1#comment39525738_25336554) (see comments)):

```
awk '
{
    n = gsub(/(^|[^[:alpha:]])is([^[:alpha:]]|$)/,"");
    printf "%s:", "is";
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", NR, (i==n?RS:",")
}' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

Comment: How can we tweak the above to get is:1,1,1,1,1,1

Comment: can this be done using just sed and awk or any Linux command (on the new format output) instead of using Perl?

Comment: The awk solution is gawk-specific courtesy of the word-delimiters `\<` and `\>`. SInce the OP can't install a newer `grep` I'd guess he doesn't have `gawk`. Although he does apparently have perl so who knows...

Comment: @EdMorton Yea, have updated the answer to reflect that. You are right, there was another question posted right after this which included a bizarre formatting request. `:)`

Comment: Yeah I saw that. It'd be easier to produce the output he now seems to want immediately rather than produce output he originally wanted but now seems to NOT want and then convert it to what he does now want. Makes no sense. Oh well...

Comment: FYI you could replace `\<` with `(^|[^[:alpha:]])` and `\>` with `([^[:alpha:]]|$)` to add a non-gawk version if you like.

Comment: @EdMorton Good idea, considering it is the accepted solution, it might help someone else looking for a vanilla `awk` solution. Thanks, have added that version. `:)`

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry for an off-topic comment, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341738/awk-count-selective-combinations-only/25343519#25343519) makes two of us waiting to see your approach. I would like to see a combination generator in awk. I spent quite a lot of time yesterday and couldn't come up with a sequence generator in `awk`. Clearly I suck at recursion.

Comment: Yesterday I just plus-1ed your perl solution and moved on as I couldn't be bothered thinking about an awk solution and I agreed with the statement that an awk one would be lengthier since it has no built-in support for generating combinations. Let me take another look and see if I can muster some enthusiasm but don't hold your breath!

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, and thanks for considering to take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o -n "is" file.txt
```

seems to work on my system.

Comment: This won't work. Put a new sentence in 1st line, can write: I don't like theasis. Then it'll end up printing: 5:is is .. you

Comment: that's why I used "-now" options (see -w). Grep version is: 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade your version of `grep`, it should fix it:

```
# grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
# grep -now is file
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
2:is
2:is
3:is
4:is
```

Imitating `grep`'s output using `perl`:

```
# perl -lne '$x = "is"; $c = () = /\b$x\b/g; while ($c--) { print "$.:$x"; }' file
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
1:is
2:is
2:is
3:is
4:is
```

Another:

```
# perl -lne '$x = "is"; $c = () = /\b$x\b/g; next unless $c--; $t = "${x}:$."; $t .= ",$." while ($c--); print $t' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,1
is:3
is:4
```

Comment: I don't think our SYS Admin will upgrade grep. Is there any other way. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I think upgrading would do. I actually didn't want to create any variables otherwise, it'd be 2 liners in shell. thanks a lot though

Comment: can this be done using just sed and awk or any Linux command (on the new format output) instead of using Perl?

Comment: @user1513848 It's more cryptic with `awk`. And probably you'd need GNU awk to make it less cryptic.