# Using sed awk how to change column1 with other columns and other columns with column1

Tags: replace, awk, grep, reverse, substitution

Using sed / awk or any Linux commands one-liner, how can i change the following lines without using Perl/other tools.

**from**

```
1:is is is is is is
2:is is
3:is
4:is
```

**to**

```
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

Comment: How do you think it should be done?

Comment: just fix whatever grep-like tool is producing the output you don't want to instead produce the output you do want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ":" }
{
    sep = "";
    n = split ($2, t, / /); 
    $2 = ""; 
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        $2 = $2 sep $1; 
        sep=","
    }
    $1 = t[1]
}1' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your previous posts, I THINK this is what you're really looking for:

```
$ cat file
This is a file, my name is Karl, what is this process, karl is karl junior, file is a test file, file's name is file.txt
My name is not Karl, my name is Karl Joey
What is your name?
Do you know your name and what it is?

$ awk -v tgt="is" '
BEGIN { FS = "(^|[^[:alpha:]])" tgt "([^[:alpha:]]|$)" }
NF>1 {
    printf "%s:", tgt
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", NR, (i<NF?",":ORS)
}' file
is:1,1,1,1,1,1
is:2,2
is:3
is:4
```

If you have GNU awk you can use `\\<` and `\\>` instead of `(^|[^[:alpha:]])` and `([^[:alpha:]]|$)`.

You should have included a line with `Is` in it (mixed case) in your sample input and expected output to show us whether or not your script should be case-sensitve. The above IS case sensitive, if that's not what you want change it to:

```
$ awk -v tgt="is" '
BEGIN { FS = "(^|[^[:alpha:]])" tolower(tgt) "([^[:alpha:]]|$)" }
{ $0 = tolower($0) }
NF>1 {
    printf "%s:", tgt
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s%s", NR, (i<NF?",":ORS)
}' file
```

Note that is is just variations of the gawk-specific answer @jaypal gave to your previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25336554/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner:

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=":" '{t=$1;split($2,a," ");$1=a[1];gsub(/[^ ]+/,t,$2)}7' file
```

### EDIT

oh, I didn't notice that you want the comma to separate the fields:

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=":" '{t=$1;split($2,a," ");$1=a[1];
                      gsub(/[^ ]+ /,t",",$2);sub(/[^,]*$/,t,$2)}7' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk -F":| " '{printf "%s,",$2;for(i=2;i<NF;i++) printf "%s,",$1;print $1}' file
is,1,1,1,1,1,1
is,2,2
is,3
is,4
```