# awk count selective combinations only:

Tags: awk

Would like to read and count the field value == "TRUE" only from 3rd field to 5th field.

Input.txt

```
Locationx,Desc,A,B,C,Locationy
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
```

While reading the headers from 3rd field to 5th field , i,e A, B, C want to generate unique combinations and permutations like A,B,C,AB,AC,AB,ABC only. 
Note: AA, BB, CC, BA etc excluded

If the "TRUE" is considered for "AB" combination count then it should not be considered for "A" conut & "B" count again to avoid duplicate ..

Example#1

```
Locationx,Desc,A,B,C,Locationy
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
```

Op#1

```
Desc,A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC
Name1,,,,,,,1
```

Example#2

```
Locationx,Desc,A,B,C,Locationy
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
```

Op#2

```
Desc,A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC
Name1,,,,1,,,
```

Example#3

```
Locationx,Desc,A,B,C,Locationy
ab123,Name1,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
```

Op#3

```
Desc,A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC
Name1,,1,,,,,
```

Desired Output:

```
Desc,A,B,C,AB,AC,BC,ABC
Name1,,,,1,,,2
Name2,,,1,,1,,1
Name3,1,,,2,,,
```

Actual File is like below :

Input.txt

```
Locationx,Desc,INCOMING,OUTGOING,SMS,RECHARGE,DEBIT,DATA,Locationy
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
```

Have tried lot , nothing is materialised , any suggestions please !!!

Edit: Desired Output from Actual Input:

```
Desc,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE,RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,SMS-DEBIT-DATA,SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DATA,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,OUTGOING-SMS-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE,INCOMING-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-SMS-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-DEBIT,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS,DEBIT-DATA,RECHARGE-DATA,RECHARGE-DEBIT,SMS-DATA,SMS-DEBIT,SMS-RECHARGE,OUTGOING-DATA,OUTGOING-DEBIT,OUTGOING-RECHARGE,OUTGOING-SMS,INCOMING-DATA,INCOMING-DEBIT,INCOMING-RECHARGE,INCOMING-SMS,INCOMING-OUTGOING,DATA,DEBIT,RECHARGE,SMS,OUTGOING,INCOMING
Name1,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Name2,,,,1,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Name3,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,
```

Don't have Perl and Python access !!!

Comment: Whats your desired output from actual file?

Comment: @jaypal Ji , have Edit desired output from Actual Input as well.

Comment: `awk` is going to be too much work. If you want, I can write some `perl` which would work.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a `perl` script that does this for you. As you can see from the size and comments, it is really simple to get this done.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings; 
use autodie;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

## change the file to the path where your file exists
open my $fh, '<', 'file';

my (%data, @new_labels);

## capture the header line in an array
my @header = split /,/, <$fh>;

## backup the header
my @fields = @header;

## remove first, second and last columns
@header = splice @header, 2, -1;

## generate unique combinations
for my $iter (1 .. +@header) {
    my $combination = combinations(\@header, $iter);
    while (my $pair = $combination->next) {
        push @new_labels, "@$pair";
    }
}

## iterate through rest of the file
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    my @line = split /,/, $line;

    ## identify combined labels that are true
    my @is_true = map { $fields[$_] } grep { $line[$_] eq "TRUE" } 0 .. $#line;

    ## increment counter in hash map keyed at description and then new labels
    ++$data{$line[1]}{$_} for map { s/ /-/g; $_ } "@is_true";
}

## print the new header
print join ( ",", "Desc", map {s/ /-/g; $_} reverse @new_labels ) . "\n";

## print the description and counter values
for my $desc (sort keys %data){     
    print join ( ",", $desc, ( map { $data{$desc}{$_} //= "" } reverse @new_labels ) ) . "\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
Desc,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE,RECHARGE-DEBIT-DATA,SMS-DEBIT-DATA,SMS-RECHARGE-DATA,SMS-RECHARGE-DEBIT,OUTGOING-DEBIT-DATA,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DATA,OUTGOING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,OUTGOING-SMS-DATA,OUTGOING-SMS-DEBIT,OUTGOING-SMS-RECHARGE,INCOMING-DEBIT-DATA,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DATA,INCOMING-RECHARGE-DEBIT,INCOMING-SMS-DATA,INCOMING-SMS-DEBIT,INCOMING-SMS-RECHARGE,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DATA,INCOMING-OUTGOING-DEBIT,INCOMING-OUTGOING-RECHARGE,INCOMING-OUTGOING-SMS,DEBIT-DATA,RECHARGE-DATA,RECHARGE-DEBIT,SMS-DATA,SMS-DEBIT,SMS-RECHARGE,OUTGOING-DATA,OUTGOING-DEBIT,OUTGOING-RECHARGE,OUTGOING-SMS,INCOMING-DATA,INCOMING-DEBIT,INCOMING-RECHARGE,INCOMING-SMS,INCOMING-OUTGOING,DATA,DEBIT,RECHARGE,SMS,OUTGOING,INCOMING
Name1,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Name2,,,,1,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Name3,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,
```

**Note:** Please revisit your expected output. It has few mistakes in it as you can see from the output generated from the script above.

Comment: [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) is a module available on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaypal for good support ,Keep Rocks ,  Let me try to install Perl into my system , currently i do have access on Bash & awk only ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at solving this using `awk`:

#### Content of `script.awk`

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }

function combinations(flds, itr,    i, pre) {
    for (i=++cnt; i<=numRecs; i++) {
        ++n
        sep = ""
        for (pre=1; pre<=itr; pre++) {
            newRecs[n] = newRecs[n] sep (sprintf ("%s", flds[pre]));
            sep = "-"
        }
        newRecs[n] = newRecs[n] sep (sprintf ("%s", flds[i])) ;
    }
}

NR==1 {
    for (fld=3; fld<NF; fld++) {
        recs[++numRecs] = $fld
    }
    for (iter=0; iter<numRecs; iter++) {
        combinations(recs, iter)
    }
    next
}

!seen[$2]++ { desc[++d] = $2 }

{
    y = 0;
    var = sep = ""
    for (idx=3; idx<NF; idx++) {
        if ($idx == "TRUE") {
            is_true[++y] = recs[idx-2]
        }
    }
    for (z=1; z<=y; z++) {
        var = var sep sprintf ("%s", is_true[z])
        sep = "-"
    }
    data[$2,var]++;
}
END{
     printf "%s," , "Desc"
    for (k=1; k<=n; k++) {
        printf "%s%s", newRecs[k],(k==n?RS:FS)
    }
    for (name=1; name<=d; name++) {
        printf "%s,", desc[name];
        for (nR=1; nR<=n; nR++) {
            printf "%s%s", (data[desc[name],newRecs[nR]]?data[desc[name],newRecs[nR]]:""), (nR==n?RS:FS)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Sample file

```
Locationx,Desc,A,B,C,Locationy
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name2,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name3,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
ab123,Name1,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,ab1234
```

#### Execution:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Desc,A,B,C,A-B,A-C,A-B-C
Name1,,,,1,,2
Name2,,,1,,1,1
Name3,1,,,2,,
```

Now, there is pretty evident bug in the `combination` function. It does not recurse to print all combinations. For eg: for `A B C D` it will print

```
A
B
C
AB
AC
ABC
```

but not `BC`